# Get photo of user from Microsoft Azure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure

In the header of the site, I display information (email, name) about the user (the information is taken from their microsoft openwork). However, I would also like to add a photo of the user. Whatever I do I get a error

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value 401 (Unauthorized)

> Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

I have already looked at many answers and tips on a similar topic, but the error does not disappear. Can you tell me how I can display the user's photo?

```
export default function UserPhoto() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value', {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}` },
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(o => {
      const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(o.data);
      setImageUrl(blobUrl)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {imageUrl && <img alt='my-user-avatar' src={imageUrl} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header.jsx

```
export default function Header() {
    return (
        <div >
            <UserInformation />
            <UserPhoto/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

getting token

```
import axios from "axios";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { config } from "../config";

const clientId = config.microsoftAuth.clientId;
const tenantId = config.microsoftAuth.tenantId;

const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read offline_access';
const tokenRequestScope = `${clientId}/.default`;
```

Comment: 401 error means there is an issue with the permissions. How are you getting the access token? Your code otherwise looks fine.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for paying attention to my question. I do not quite understand your question, since I am not strong in the topic of tokens. Here is an example code:
const baseUrl = `${host}/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0`;
let tokensRequestUrl = `${baseUrl}/token?`;
const response = await axios.post(tokensRequestUrl, body, config);

Comment: I believe the issue is with the token only. Please check the token using something like https://jwt.io. Please check the scopes in the decrypted token.

Comment: @GauravMantri If I understand you correctly, then the parsed token has the following column: "scp": "User.Read"

Comment: The scope is correct. What are the Graph API permissions assigned to the application in Azure AD?

Comment: @GauravMantri I assume you are talking about offline_access? const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read offline_access'

Comment: Yeah. Can you please edit your question and include the complete code for getting the token? I want to see the data sent in that request.

Comment: Check if the access token is expired?

Comment: @Rukmini The code has a check for an expired access token, and if this check fails, then the access token is updated automatically

Comment: Is the Admin Consent granted for the API permissions?

Comment: @Rukmini where can i check this (Is the Admin Consent granted for the API permissions?)

Comment: Go to the Azure AD Application -> API Permissions and check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/t6tjB9x.png).

Comment: @Rukmini This will take some time, I will get back to you with an answer later.

Comment: @Rukmini Yes, such permission was not granted. I asked to be corrected. But I still get this 401 error, just a little different: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254004/discussion-between-rukmini-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD SPA application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I used the below endpoint to **authorize users**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

Code got generated like below:

[image]

Now, I generated the **access token using PKCE flow via Postman** by passing parameters like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, the **scp** is `Directory.Read.All`, `User.Read`, `profile`, `openid` ,`email` like below:

[image]

***I am able to fetch the profile photo successfully like below***:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

[image]

The error **`401Unauthorized`** usually occurs if there are no required permissions to perform the action.

[image]

**To resolve the error**, check the below:

In your code modify the below changes:

```js
const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read offline_access';
const tokenRequestScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
```

- Make sure that the **aud** must be **`https://graph.microsoft.com`**
- Make sure that you have granted **Admin consent** to the API permissions:

[image]

- As you granted `Directory.Read.All`, `User.Read` API permissions check if the same reflects in the **scp** parameter when the token is decoded.
- Make sure that the access token is not expired and the process of refreshing the access token is configured properly.

**Reference:**

[Get profilePhoto - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#to-retrieve-the-profile-photo-of-a-user)